# select menu and inside menu active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, menu

I have table named menu :

user | id | parent | title | link

parent - contain Id of the parent menu (if 0 mean no parent, other mean it's sub menu)

id - auto increse integer

title,link - for showing the menu

I want to get those data with SELECT active record (codeignaotr) and I don't konw how to do that.

simaply I would use something like this (didn't check this code it's only for example!):
-not in active record

```
    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT `id`,`parent`,`text`, `link` FROM `menu` where `user`=$user);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id=$row['id'];
        $text=$row['text'];                             
        $link=$row['link'];
        $subs=0;

        if($result2=$mysqli->query("SELECT `id`,`text`, `link` FROM `menu` WHERE `parent`=$id")){
            while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){  
                $id_sub[]=$row['id'];
                $text_sub[]=$row['text'];                               
                $link_sub[]=$row['link'];
            ++$subs;
            }//query
        }//if   

    }//query
```

What is the best way to get array of all menus in this format:

$menu['title']

$menu['link']

$menu['sub']['title']  (and etc..)

with codeigantor active record?

Comment: You are not using `activerecord` try this : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I know that example isn't active record... I asking how to do it in active record... and I already read this article

Comment: So you don't get it how to do it?

Comment: In my example the 2nd query is inside the first result , how I do that in active record?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way it might help:

```
$this->db->select('id,parent,text,link');
$this->db->from('menu');
$this->db->where('user',$user);
$query = $this->db->get();
$addrows = $query->result();
foreach($allrows as $onerow){
    $this->db->select('id,text,link');
    $this->db->from('menu');
    $this->db->where('parent',$onerow->id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $subrows[] = $query->result();
}
print_r($subrows);
```

It might be something like this but you need to improve it. Looks like you are comparing your `id` with `parent` field in your second query so improve it if it's wrong.

Comment: your code need some fixs, but it really helped me to get what I look for. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am just converting your mysql query to active record.... I hope this will help you.
1st Query:

```
$result = $this->db->select('id, parent, text, link')->where('user', $user)->from('menu')->get()->result();
```

2nd Query:

```
$result2 = $this->db->select('id, text, link')->where('parent', $id)->from('menu')->get()->result();
```

Comment: in my example the 2nd query is inside the first one, how can I do it?